# How can I write a svn export command using php?

Tags: php, exec, nant

I want to export some files from my server. For that I created one php page. How can I write svn export command in php.

I call this php file from a nant script. Nant script command is like this. I need to write it on php script.

```
    <exec program="svn.exe" basedir="${svnexedir}" commandline="export  --force  "${tagrepo}/DevScripts/install.php/" "${localrepo}/myTest/DevScripts/install.php/"" />
```

Comment: What is `<exec ...>` supposed to be...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either search around for a PHP svn module.

Or, easier (potentially better), just use exec() or one of the functions like it.

http://php.net/exec